# R replicate sample function without replacement

Tags: r, random, replace, portfolio, replicate

I want to sample 5 random rows 1,000 times and summarize them in a data frame. I have a problem with the `replace = FALSE` and I wonder where to put it to `replace = TRUE`.

I have a dataset of 5,000 rows which looks (simplified) like this:

```
 Fund.ID Vintage Type Region.Focus Net.Multiple  Size
[1,] 4716  2003  2    US           1.02          Small
[2,] 2237  1998  25   Europe       0.03          Medium
[3,] 1110  1992  2    Europe       1.84          Medium
[4,] 12122 1997  25   Asia         2.04          Large 
[5,] 5721  2006  25   US           0.86          Mega
[6,] 730   1998  2    Europe       0.97          Small
```

This is my function which starts with one random row and includes a constraint for the 5 rows being drawn.:

```
       simulate <- function(inv.period) {
          start <- sample_n(dataset, 1, replace=TRUE) #draw random first fund
          t <- start$Vintage:(start$Vintage + inv.period) #define investment period contingent on first fund
          fof <- dataset[sample(which(dataset$Vintage %in% t), 5, replace = FALSE), ] #include constraint, 5 funds in portfolio
        }

#replicate this function 1,000 times 
#and give out as a data frame with portfolios classified
        library(plyr)
        library(dplyr)
        fof.5 <- rdply(1000, simulate(4))
        rename(fof.5, FoF.ID = .n)
```

If I use `replace=FALSE` in the simulate function (after fof <-), I get this error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
> The whole expression works if I put replace = TRUE. However, this would not be correct, as a row could be drawn twice in the same sample, which I do not want.

Is there a way to put `replace=FALSE` when rows are drawn, but put `replace=TRUE` for the overall dataset? It should be: A row can be drawn only once within the sample but can be drawn another time in another sample.

Comment: If you use a function from a package please indicate with `library(package)` it helps others to replicate your code and find solutions.

Comment: The function `simulate` does not return any value. It will also fail any time the length of `t` is less than `5`. For example, let's say `start` returns row 4 from its sample. Then `start$Vintage` will be `1997`. Now let's say `inv.period` is 1. Two values are being sampled, rows 2 and 4. You are asking for 5 values to be extracted without replacement. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am using the plyr and dplyr packages, as indicated in the second code box. It is true that my simulate function does not return any value. That is because i store the replicated function output as a dataframe with the rdply function. Since I have a large dataset (5,000 rows) with years 1982-2015, your second point raised should not result in problems.

Comment: fof.5 <- do.call( rbind, replicate(1000, simulate(5), simplify=FALSE ) ) works, but I cannot distinguish draw 1 from draw 2 etc. I want to add an additional column with variable "FoF" which is equal to 1 for the first sample, 2 for the second etc.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between `sample_n(dataset, 1, replace=TRUE)` and `sample_n(dataset, 1, replace=FALSE)`?

Comment: You are referring to the first sample expression. In this case it does make a difference. If I put start <- sample_n(dataset, 1, replace=FALSE), the error persists. I need to change the second sample expression to TRUE, which is unwanted: I would get samples in which a row can be drawn twice.

Comment: As mentioned,  fof.5 <- do.call( rbind, replicate(1000, simulate(5), simplify=FALSE ) ) works now. However, how can I mark each sample, e.g. with a separate column (draw1, draw2 etc.)?

Comment: We could fix the `do.call` expression but the function has serious issues that have to be resolved. You cannot draw 5 examples from a Vintage match of less than 5.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that at least 5 matches will always be found. Look at the example. If the sample is `2003` it will then add 5 more investment periods up to `2008`. But that match will only be of length 2. That is rows 1 and 5. It will fail in that case because you are forcing the dataset to pull 5 values out. It is impossible to pull 5 unique rows from two rows. You are skating over an important weakness in your logic.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know what you are using this for. Is it okay if the investment period is 4 but the draw is only 3 periods?

Comment: I want to simulate random funds-of-funds. Each row is a fund. An investment period of 4 years means that the fund-of-fund _can_ only invest in these periods, but does not have to invest in each of these 4 years. The number of investments has to be as specified though, so if I put 5 funds per portfolio, it needs to be 5 funds.

Comment: If you do not get 5 fund matches in a random sample, how will you get 5 funds out, repeat some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking out the `dplyr` stuff, there is no need for it. Secondly, add a variable for the matches called `matches` to then sample the length of that vector or the number 5, whichever is smaller. Lastly, I would use `data.table::rbindlist`, it has an argument to create an index indicating which draw was taken. The output will be a `data.table`, if you are not familiar with it, you can use `as.data.frame(rbindlist(....))` at the end to turn it back to a data.frame.:

```
library(data.table)
simulate <- function(inv.period) {
  start <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), 1, replace=TRUE),]
  t <- start$Vintage:(start$Vintage + inv.period)
  matches <- which(dataset$Vintage %in% t)
  dataset[sample(matches, min(length(matches),5), replace = FALSE), ]
}

r <- replicate(1000, simulate(5), simplify=FALSE)
rbindlist(r, idcol="draw")
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I added the as.data.frame() expression at the end and now I have a data frame just as I wanted.

Comment: When I run the function e.g. for an investment period of 5 years and 15, 25, 30 or even 100 rows in the sample, the function does not work properly: some samples have fewer than the specified number of rows (e.g. 2 instead of 50), whereas other samples have the specified number of rows. I do realize that this is due to limited number of rows I have for some years (and that start is unconstrained) How can I solve this problem? Could I somehow already put constraints in the first start sample?

Comment: You cannot extract what is not there. There is no code possible to create more data for you, you have to work with what you have.

Comment: I understand that the dataset is somewhat too small. However, the issue here is more that the `which()` and `min(lenght(matches))` expressions are not restrictive enough. If I simulate only a few samples, the same issue arises. Thus, the problem can possibly be solved by changing the first start expression (e.g. with a `which()` function that recognizes that if the desired sample is big, then it should only take data after 1996 (that's when I have much more rows).